# Django 1.10 TemplateSyntaxError. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I'm trying to load a css file from my static folder, and the "TemplateSyntaxError" is showing in this line:

[Here is the code that I'm using to load a template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7tm7.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

<title>{% block title %} Portuaria {% endblock %}</title>
```

[And this is the error that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4edZR.png)

Am I trying to load the template in a wrong way?

I'm using django v 1.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this at the top of your html file

```
{% load static %}
```